# Retrieving data from usual and join tables in cakephp 3.5

Tags: cakephp, join

In this example from the book:

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#using-the-through-option

```
class StudentsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->belongsToMany('Courses', [
            'through' => 'CoursesMemberships',
        ]);
    }
}

class CoursesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->belongsToMany('Students', [
            'through' => 'CoursesMemberships',
        ]);
    }
}

class CoursesMembershipsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->belongsTo('Students');
        $this->belongsTo('Courses');
    }
}
```

i can see the list of Courses related to each Student in students/view/N because I have the following code in the StudentsController:

```
public function view($id = null)
    {
        $student = $this->Students->get($id, [
            'contain' => ['Cources']
        ]);

        $this->set('student', $student);
        $this->set('_serialize', ['student']);

    }
```

If I replace Courses by CoursesMemberships there:

```
public function view($id = null)
    {
        $student = $this->Students->get($id, [
            'contain' => ['CoursesMemberships']
        ]);

        $this->set('student', $student);
        $this->set('_serialize', ['student']);

    }
```

and make corresponding changes in Students/view.ctp, I can see the list of related CoursesMemberships.

How to see both? I mean, what should be in StudentsController so that I can see in the same view (better in the same table) for each Student both, related Courses and days_attended and grade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the first variant, ie contain `Courses`, the join table data will be available in the `Course` entities `_joinData` property.

```
$course->_joinData->days_attended
$course->_joinData->grade
```

Comment: I there a way to add, view, edit and delete from this table 'CoursesMemberships' using the generated by Cake code? Index works, it lists all entries correctly, the rest end up giving the 'InvalidPrimaryKeyException'.